# codechef: A puzzle game

Tags: c++, algorithm, depth-first-search

**problem statement:**

Johnny has some difficulty memorizing the small prime numbers. So, his computer science teacher has asked him to play with the following puzzle game frequently.

The puzzle is a 3x3 board consisting of numbers from 1 to 9. The objective of the puzzle is to swap the tiles until the following final state is reached:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

At each step, Johnny may swap two adjacent tiles if their sum is a prime number. Two tiles are considered adjacent if they have a common edge.

Help Johnny to find the shortest number of steps needed to reach the goal state.

**My solution so far**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

bool prime[20];

int matrix[3][3];
int solved[3][3] = {
    {1,2,3},
    {4,5,6},
    {7,8,9}
};

void display()
{
    for(int row = 0; row<3;row++)
        {
            for(int col = 0;col<3;col++)
            {
                cout<<matrix[row][col]<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
        cout<<endl<<endl;

}

bool check(){
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            if(matrix[i][j]!=solved[i][j])
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int min(int a,int b)
{
    return (a<b)?a:b;
}

void generate(){
    memset(prime,true,sizeof(prime));
    for(int i=2;i*i<20;i++){
        if(prime[i]==true)
        {
            for(int j=2*i;j<20;j+=i)
                prime[j]=false;
        }
    }
}

int getMoves(int row, int col){
    if(row < 0 ||col< 0 || row>=3||col>=3){
        return 0;
    }
    if(check()){
        return 0;
    }

    int moves = 0;

    for(int i = row-1 ; i<= row+1 ;i++)
    {
        for(int j = col -1 ; j<=col+1;j++)
        {
            if((i!=row-1&&j!=col-1)||(i!=row+1&&j!=col+1)||(i!=row+1&&j!=col-1)||(i!=row-1&&j!=col+1)){

                if(prime[matrix[row][col]+matrix[i][j]]==true)
                {
                    moves+=getMoves(i,j);
                    int temp;
                    temp = matrix[i][j];
                    matrix[i][j] = matrix[row][col];
                    matrix[row][col] = temp;
                    display();
                }
            }   
        }
    }
    return moves;
}

int Moves(){
    int minMoves = INF;
    for(int row = 0;row<3;row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0;col<3;col++)
        {
            int moves = getMoves(row,col);
            minMoves = min(moves,minMoves);
        }
    }
    return minMoves;
}



int main(){
    generate();
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        for(int row = 0; row<3;row++)
        {
            for(int col = 0;col<3;col++)
            {
                cin>>matrix[row][col];
            }
        }

    }
    cout<<Moves();
}
```

**sample testcase**

```
Input:
2

7 3 2 
4 1 5 
6 8 9 

9 8 5 
2 4 1 
3 7 6  

Output:
6
-1
```

the program keeps crashing I guess because of memory overflow issue.

Comment: Don't use `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`. Ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid your code is completely wrong and I don't think it could by fixed without complete rewrite. For example in function `getMoves()` your variables `i` and `j` can acquire value -1 so you will face access violation error. Secondly you have a recursion there, but you don't change data before you invoke recursion. Let's assume you want to swap 7 and 4. In the next step (because you didn't change input) you can swap 4 and 1. But it's not a correct move, because in that time, 4 should't be there. Thirdly your function `getMoves()` can end in an endless loop.

In conclusion, these kinds of problem are solved quite differently. You can for exmaple use [backtracking algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) or you can use [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm). You will have to evaluate your current state. Let assume the following state:

```
7 3 2
4 5 6
1 8 9
```

You can measure number of moves that the number has to do to go to its correct position. So in this case `1` has to do 2 moves, `7` has to do 2 moves, `2` has to do 1 move as well as the number `3`. The value of this state is `2 + 2 + 1 + 1 = 6`. It's called an heuristic function. Now you can take this function and put it in an A* algorithm, and you should see the correct result.

Comment: now i get it.. thank you so much.. i guess i will try to implement using backtracking algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (row < 0 || col< 0 || row >= 3 || row <= 3) {
    return 0;
}
```

The code after this part is 'not accessible' because this condition is always true `(... row >= 3 || row <= 3)`. You probably meant to write: `(... row >= 3 || col >= 3)`